# Distance for degree on the Earth

Tags: sql, gis, distance, geospatial, spatialite

At one of questions I seen the below answer ::

**Based on average distance for degress in the Earth.**

**1° = 111km;**

can anybody say how this transformation is done ?

is it will be same for each place on the earth ?

Comment: The question about how the transformation is done is not related to programming.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math

Comment: Hello, yes it's kind of math. but it contains the logic for programming.. without the understanding how can somebody write logic without it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equatorial circumference of the earth is ~40000km.

There are 360 degrees.

Divide one by the other.

So this only applies at the circumference, and decreases the closer you get to the poles.

So it's not an average, but a maximum.

Comment: ok, so it will not be same at each point of earth. If we are creating 100KM buffer on two different part of earth how can handle this situation ? ... Might you can able to answer me for one more related question to this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882853/gis-buffer-value-degree-to-meters-with-spatiallite